# Executing SQL query through VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, sql-server, sql

I am new here, but I always check this website whenever I have issues with excel and so far you've always helped me!
Now I have a problem with VBA: I want to "call" an SQL query through a macro, so basically copy pasting the data coming from the query, to my active sheet.

I tried with the following query I found on this website (I am not sure which was the thread since I checked so many before asking it myself):

```
Sub sql()
'Initializes variables
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String

'Setup the connection string for accessing MS SQL database
   'Make sure to change:
       '1: PASSWORD
       '2: USERNAME
       '3: REMOTE_IP_ADDRESS
       '4: DATABASE
    ConnectionString = connString = "Driver={"mydriver"};Server="myserver";Database="mydatabase";UID="Myuserid";PWD="mypwd";Port=PortNum;SSL=true;Sslmode=Require"

    'Opens connection to the database
    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    'Timeout error in seconds for executing the entire query; this will run for 15 minutes before VBA timesout, but your database might timeout before this value
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    'This is your actual MS SQL query that you need to run; you should check this query first using a more robust SQL editor (such as HeidiSQL) to ensure your query is valid
    StrQuery = "Select * from YYY.XXXX where date >='2020-03-01'"

    'Performs the actual query
    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
    'Dumps all the results from the StrQuery into cell A2 of the first sheet in the active workbook
    Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst
End Sub
```

This is the error I get: 
[RuntimeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLucK.png)

I tried googling the error and I found I should have the server in my system32; I checked in "computer management" but I don't have anything related to SQL there.

Do you have any suggestions?

I apologize in advance if there is another thread about the same issue, but I couldn't find anything to solve it so far.

EDIT: I did not include the TABLE, user id and pwd as it's sensitive data I cannot share online; however, my issue is with Driver, Server and Database; I am not sure what to input there. Also, where should I put the URL for my query (jdbc:...)?

I usually use SQL workbench to get the data and I copy paste it in a worksheet every week; this is what I would like for the macro to do instead.
Sorry if I didn't explain it all correctly before the edit.

Comment: you need to update this with real values, `ConnectionString = connString = "Driver={"mydriver"};Server="myserver";Database="mydatabase";UID="Myuserid";PWD="mypwd";Port=PortNum;SSL=true;Sslmode=Require"`,, replace `mydriver` with the True name and so others! And check whether this is `matching_ddl.brand_curation_curation_metrics` the real TABLE name  or not !!

Comment: Hi Rajesh, yes, I did update them, I didn't leave them in the original message as it's sensitive data I use at work :) My problem is that I don't know what to input for Server, Database, and Driver... I take data from Redshift, if that helps

Comment: Hi @Lisa Sakajawea ,, I don't think since Redshift is cloud based database, and the used method is for local database !

Comment: Oh, I understand... I was not aware that this was a local database, honestly! Can you redirect me to a macro which does the same on a cloud based database, instead?

Comment: ,, if fact I've never tried the Redshift but U just check [this link](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/redshift-odbc-excel-query.rst) or [this one also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430175/connecting-to-amazon-redshift-via-excel-macro-odbc-connection-string-to-amazon),,, ☺

Comment: Great, I'll check those! Thank you :)

Comment: If you can manually create a data connection, then record a macro of you creating it. It will give you the proper connection string.

Comment: Totally off-topic, but have you considered using MS Query to populate your data in the spreadsheet instead of using VBA?  Here is a step-by-step example.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51437286/choose-as400-query-records-directly-from-excel/51444029#51444029.  The example is DB2, but it will work with any ODBC connection